# Update table row based on cell value jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a contacts table that contains a column for `contact_id`. Can someone help me update a table row based on `contact_id`? For example, I have the following table:

```
<table class="table table-condensed" id="company_contacts_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone #</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      <th hidden></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Jake</td>
        <td>Dang</td>
        <td>jake123@gmail.com</td>
        <td>7032669955</td>
        <td>contact_notes</td>
        <td><button type="update" class="btn btn-primary update_contact" href="#update_contact_modal" data-toggle="modal" id="some_contact_id">Update</button></td>
        <td><button type="update" class="btn btn-danger delete_contact" id="some_contact_id">Delete</button></td>
        <td hidden>some_contact_id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Harrison</td>
        <td>WElls</td>
        <td>Hwells@gmail.com</td>
        <td>7039998888</td>
        <td>contact_notes</td>
        <td><button type="update" class="btn btn-primary update_contact" href="#update_contact_modal" data-toggle="modal" id="some_contact_id2">Update</button></td>
        <td><button type="update" class="btn btn-danger delete_contact" id="some_contact_id2">Delete</button></td>
        <td hidden>some_contact_id2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mason</td>
        <td>Hanley</td>
        <td>mnahley@gmail.com</td>
        <td>7032669855</td>
        <td>contact_notes</td>
        <td><button type="update" class="btn btn-primary update_contact" href="#update_contact_modal" data-toggle="modal" id="some_contact_id3">Update</button></td>
        <td><button type="update" class="btn btn-danger delete_contact" id="some_contact_id3">Delete</button></td>
        <td hidden>some_contact_id3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Each row contains a hidden `contact_id` column. I want to update the first name, last name, email, phone #, notes based on the contact id. Sample pseudocode:

var my_contact_id = some_contact_id

```
var new_first_name = 'george'
var new_last_name = 'henry'
var new_email = 'tinpopo@hotmail.com'
var new_phone = 999-333-4444

- Find row that contains `some_contact_id`
- Set first name, last name, email, phone to new first name, new last name, new email, new phone
```

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which jQuery selectors have you tried that aren't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var new_first_name = 'george'
var new_last_name = 'henry'
var new_email = 'tinpopo@hotmail.com'
var new_phone = 999-333-4444

var tr = $("#company_contacts_table td:contains("+some_contact_id+")").closest("tr").find("td");
tr[0].innerHTML = new_first_name;
tr[1].innerHTML = new_last_name;
tr[2].innerHTML = new_email;
tr[3].innerHTML = new_phone;
```

Comment: Hi - I just tried this, but `tr` is returning `[]`.. My exact code was:

`var tr = $("#company_contacts_table").find('66fa33a1-1f7f-43f7-b524-de2cac543b4e').closest("tr").find("td");`

`console.log(tr)`

returns `[]`

Comment: @user1547174 OK I fixed it. Now it will work for you.